# Get post insights (API)

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-insights

Is there any way the API can provide insights about all posts which belong to a FB page (ideally in one API call)?

The FB insights (non-API), provide this information (as a downloadable Excel file), so it should be available somewhere.

There is the FB page insights API call ([here](https://graph.facebook.com/132081276879158/insights)), but this doesn't also provide info about the posts of the page. Any help?

Comment: What kind of insights do you want ?
Do you want them post by post or on aggregate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve post information using this call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/posts
```

Facebook added this in Oct '11: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/573/